# Are default parameters with non-static defaults legit?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am currently refactoring some internal Angular libraries and ran  across a function for a mockup service that looks very much like this:

```
private createRandomItem(property: PropOne,
                        anotherProperty: PropTwo,
                        yetAnotherProperty: PropThree): Item {
    const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() + 0.5);
    const part = rand === 0 ? null : {
        id: AnotherClass.generateId(),
        prop2: anotherProperty,
        prop3: yetAnotherProperty
    };
    return {
        part: part,
        prop1: property
    };
}
```

I changed it into this:

```
private createRandomItem(property: PropOne,
                        anotherProperty: PropTwo = AnotherClass.getRandomPropTwo(),
                        yetAnotherProperty: PropThree = AnotherClass.getRandomPropThree(),
                        isPartEnabled: Boolean = Math.random() > 0.5): Item {
    const part = isPartEnabled ? null : {
        id: AnotherClass.generateId(),
        prop2: anotherProperty,
        prop3: yetAnotherProperty
    };
    return {
        part: part,
        prop1: property
    };
}
```

Basically i introduced default values inside the signature and by that i made the function calls shorter:

```
// Before
const item = createRandomItem(prop, 
                              AnotherClass.getRandomPropTwo(), 
                              AnotherClass.getRandomPropThree())
// After
const item = createRandomItem(prop)
```

In case someone wants to set the properties by themselves both  signatures can be used without a problem and even the randomizer can be passed in if wanted (in most cases only the first argument will be used, i think).

**My question now is this:** 
Is the usage of parameter default values a good idea if the default values depend on other functions return values? Also while we are at it i would really like to know if this improves the code quality. I think it makes the signature a bit ugly, but i also think its worth it.

Since this is not entirely objective i wanted to add what i look for in the answers:

- Coding conventions that discuss this issue (haven't found anything)
- Better ways to declare this function
- Arguments for and against the usage of functions inside parameter default value declarations

Comment: I dont think StackOverflow handles code reviews. May be https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: I just wanted to set the context and i don't want anyone to review the code. As i stated in my question, i want to know: "Is the usage of parameter default values a good idea if the default values depend on other functions return values?"

Comment: @sabithpocker thanks for that tip! I didn't know about that stackexchange!

Comment: Sorry, I don't know exactly if the question fits here, but the other place will have more people expecting this type of questions.

Comment: Default arguments allow you to omit checking if an argument is undefined. In other words: you move code from the body to the signature. That's not exactly what you did. Also keep in mind that by calling other functions you couple your function.